# 7z Command Line Extract code does not extract files into specified folder

Tags: 7zip

I have written a command line extract code :

```
7z x C:\\Users\\Anuj\\Desktop\\th.7z -p123 -oC:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN *.* -r"
```

Here the given Output path is :

```
C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN *.* -r"
```

However The zip file gets extracted to :

```
C:\Program\
```

I have identified the problem too, the problem is the code cannot take spaces in file folder.if the file output is changed to `C:\\ProgramFiles\\OpenVpn`
It works. BUt if the path is `C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN` It doesnt

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the ACCESS DENIED error for the code below:

```
declare @unzip varchar(500)
set @unzip='"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e D:\Documents\test_compress.zip -oD:\Documents\test_compress'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @unzip
```

All I had to do was allow the MSSQL application the FULL ACCESS control. To do that first find the application name :

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami' -- nt service\mssqlserver
```

Now go to D:\Documents - Right Click the Documents folder - Click "Properties - Go to "Security" tab -- If MSSQLSERVER is not listed then Click "Edit" and then click "Add" -- Add "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER" and now check the option "Full Control" Allow

Comment: Please be sure to look at your post afterward, to make sure it's formatted correctly. I had to fix it, since you didn't format your command line code, and used underlines which inadvertently bolded everything into header text.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/syntax.htm

Wildcards or filenames with spaces must be quoted:

```
"Dir\Program files\*"
Dir\"Program files"\*
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I get a new error Access is Denied on the PRogram Files folder

Comment: Does your user account have write permissions to Program Files? Is the password in your script correct?

Comment: I think you don't have access to create files in Program Files folder